# IE not updating hover state after jquery add/remove class when mouse stands still

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, hover

Here is a fiddle for you: https://jsfiddle.net/u1a4j3br/1/

I have a very weird behaviour here. Try to hover over the red square, then move your mouse to the right, where the square expanded to. Now perform a click, and you will see, the hover state is being removed, and added half a second later, so it will be ready for additional hovers. If you try this in a normal browser like Chrome, Opera, FF etc. it will work, even when your mouse is not moving in the 0,5 seconds.

Now, try the same in IE. You will see, it also works when the mouse is being moved, however, it will NOT work, when the mouse is not being moved. In that case, after 0.5 seconds, the square jumps right back to its hover state.

This is the affected div i set up for testing purposes:

```
<div id="myDiv" class="test" onclick="removeHover()"></div>
```

and this is the css for the "test"-class:

```
.test{
    height:100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: red;
}
```

The

```
function removeHover(){

    $('.test').addClass('nohover');

    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.test').removeClass('nohover');
    },50);

}
```

should actually supress the behaviour, because it does at the same time hides the hover part of the div, as I want to doanyways, and it interrupts the hovering for a short amount of time, by pulling the div from under the mouse (so basically the opposite of the usual pulling the mouse away from the div) by playing together with some css hover manipulation:

```
.test:not(.nohover):hover{
    width:400px;
    background: yellow;
}
```

Note that the .nohover is no css class, it's just some placeholder to block the hover event.

I suspect IE only updates possibly hover states after any mouse movements. Obviously it can't really be JQuery, as it actually is working.

Is there a way to force it to update instead, to prevent this behaviour? 
(Some ideas on how to actually find out what's the problem with the mouse here might help as well)

So far I only have the idea to wait for a mouse movement before removing the class again, but I hope there's a more elegant way to do this.

EDIT: [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/u1a4j3br/3/) is the solution from my idea. This actually works by adding a mousemove handler, which removes the class on the first mouse movement, and then unbinds the listener, but I don't really like it. Would prefer something closer to my first approach, with the timeout. I don't prefer relying on mouse events.

Comment: That's an interresting question/bug but you have to post relevant code in question itself

Comment: Do you mean I should extract some from the fiddle? I can do that of course

Comment: Ya, you have to post it in question itself, otherwise, if jsFiddle link is shutdown for some reason, your question here on SO is still useful for futur readers

Comment: Alright. Hope that works out.

Comment: Now regarding this bug, i guess your best bet is to not use CSS `:hover` pseudo class but instead use js or jq solution

Comment: Seems to be an IE bug - https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/926665/ie-11-hovering-over-an-element-and-then-scrolling-without-moving-the-mouse-pointer-leaves-the-element-in-hover-state (the test case is pretty similar)